# mysql error: mysql_handledberror: Success

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04

I am implementing a virtual LTE EPC setup which requires a mysql database for one of its modules (HSS). After creating that, I had to run that module but receive the error as shown in the screenshot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGHtG.png).
P.S. I'm new to this stuff

Comment: You might want to ask on https://serverfault.com since this is more of an installation than a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

you must modify the password of your sql script, please in your terminal:

```
vim src/mysql.cpp
```

Line 6 and modify the default password:

```
passwd = "mysql";
```

to your sql password.

you must re run your code to make sure that the changes apply